# How to force Wordpress to show page and ignore rest of link

Tags: php, wordpress

Hei !
I trying to implement some new script into Wordpress.
Script is not created for wordpress so I have to improvise.
I created page called auctions so link looks like:

> www.example.com/auctions

Inside that page php code implementing script, so page is showing up what it's supposed to show.
But then when i'm going to some under-page (in that new script) for example:

> www.example.com/auctions/add-new

Wordpress is showing 404-page not found. How to stop wordpress after /auctions/ even if page will be called:

> www.example.com/auctions/something/somethingelse/someothercode

In such a way that wordpress will allways showes 'auctions' page?

Comment: you mean any subpage under auctions page will make Auctions page open and not subpage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook:

```
    add_action('template_redirect','my_redirect');

        function my_redirect(){
            global $wp; //global $wp object it will return us request

            if ( in_array($wp->request,array('auctions','auctions/new'))) :
                add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_wp_title', 10, 2 );
                status_header( 200 ); 
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/my-page-template.php');
                exit;
            endif;
        }

function change_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $wp;

    if(in_array($wp->request,array('auctions','auctions/new'))){
        $title = get_bloginfo('name') . $sep . ' Auction';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: For "auctions" this is perfect, but when I going into "auctions/new" header changing for 404 and page title is "Page not found" but content is correct.

Comment: @Davny check i've modified the answer.

Comment: Title is now perfect, but header is still changing for the one from 404 page. Thats not a big problem, i can make it looks better. Thanks for help !